# Input validation and input processing

Tags: python, arrays, validation, input, typeerror

I'm having quite a hard time creating this program.
Basically the goal is to request user input 7 times, validate the user input based on the criteria of being `>= 0` and a valid real number, create a list of that input, then process the input to output `Total`, `max`, `min`, and `average`.

```
MAX_HOURS=7

def get_string(prompt):
    value=""
    value=input(prompt)
    return int(value)

def get_pints(pints):
    counter = 0

    while counter < MAX_HOURS:
        pints[counter] = get_real("How many pints were donated? ")
        counter = counter + 1
    return counter

def valid_real(value):
    while True:
        try:
            value=float(value)
            if value >= 0:
                return True
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid number greater than 0! ")
                return False
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number greater than 0! ")
            return False, int(value)

def get_real(prompt)
    value=""
    value=input(prompt)
    while not valid_real(value):
        print(value, "is not a valid entry. Please enter a number greater than 0")
        value=input(prompt)
    return value



 def get_total_pints(pints):
    counter = 0
    total_pints = 0.0

    while counter < 7:
        total_pints = total_pints + pints[MAX_HOURS]
        counter = counter + 1
    return total_pints


def get_min_pints(pints):
    min_pints = pints[MAX_HOURS]
    min_pints = 0 
    for i in range(7):
        if i < min_pints:
            min_pints = i
    return min_pints

def get_max_pints(pints):
    max_pints = pints
    max_pints = 0
    for i in range (MAX_HOURS):
        if i > max_pints:
            max_pints = i
    return max_pints

def get_average_pints(total_pints):
    average_pints = 0
    average_pints=total_pints / MAX_HOURS
    return average_pints

def full_program():
    pints=[0 for i in range(MAX_HOURS)]
    max_pints=[0 for i in range(MAX_HOURS)]
    total_pints=[0 for i in range(MAX_HOURS)]
    counter=0
    pints=get_pints(pints)
    total_pints = get_total_pints(pints)
    print([pints])
    print(int(total_pints))

full_program()
```

While I'm pretty sure my input validation loop is correct, it seems like the main issue is that I have a an `int` object that can't be subscripted. I've read other posts and tried some of the code that worked in those scenarios, but I can't get my program to run correctly.
I'm really struggling and at this point, any guidance in the right direction is appreciated.
EDIT: I sent some of the wrong code, I've been revising this code so much I got mixed up on what I meant to send.
Also:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/classwork 1125/lab5original.py", line 193, in <module>
    full_program()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/classwork 1125/lab5original.py", line 182, in full_program
    total_pints = get_total_pints(pints)
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/classwork 1125/lab5original.py", line 97, in get_total_pints
    total_pints = total_pints + pints[MAX_HOURS]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: In get_pints, why do you return counter and more importantly, str(pints)?  I think you just want to return pints.  The point is there really isn't enough info to go on here.  A stack trace or other indication of exactly what the problem is would help, more than "can't get my program to run correctly."

Comment: Is `def get_real(prompt: object) -> object:` really your intended code? In which context is this valid Python 3 syntax?

Comment: I see both of your points, and have edited my original post with those edits, I've been revising and pulled this code from the wrong file

Comment: It seems like you want `pints` to be the list that you created in `full_program`, but 1) variables created in one function are not visible in a different function; 2) `pints` is an integer inside `get_total_pints` because you're passing an integer to the function as an argument. If you need a value to be globally accessible, then create it at the global level, rather than inside a "main" function; and choose more descriptive variable names that keep pints-the-list separate from pints-the-int.